# For loop only outputs last iteration

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop, document.write

I am new to Javascript and am just playing around trying to print a simple for loop to the HTML.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="hello"</div>
```

**JS :**

```
var text="";

for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {
    document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML=text+i;
}
```

My problem is that this code only outputs the last iteration '9', and not '0123456789' which is what I want.

Now if i do `document.write` it prints out the numbers fine but I heard this is bad practice so I just want to do it the correct way.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It would be better to build your text content first and insert it into HTML element once (to save some time):

```
var text="";

for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {
    text += i;
}

document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = text;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the addition assignment operator `+=` that adds a value to a variable, so you're just missing `+` before `=` in :

```
document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML += text+i;
```

**NOTE :** Use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` because you're appending just a text, check example bellow.

---

```js
var text="";
for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {
    document.getElementById("hello").textContent += text+i;
}
```

```html
<div id="hello"></div>
```

Comment: Great,  so to add a value to a variable I always use +=. Got it thanks for your help.