# Why text is not showing correct when the value matches

Tags: javascript, html

I was recently generating numbers between `0` & `1` which matches the `index` of one of the two `btn` it will be treated as lucky and changes `color` to `green` else `color` changes to `red` and text will show that other is lucky .

Everything works alright but the text is coorect for 1 `btn` only , i.e , it will show correct text as I am lucky but not make correct sense for other `btn`

> You can see by clicking the 1st btn : When it is right , i.e , green color text should be "I am lucky" but it shows "Other btn is lucky"

```js
var btnLuck = document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON");

function randomNumber()
  {
  var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = randNum;

console.log('randNum =',randNum ) // ------------------

  for (let i = 0; i < btnLuck.length; i++)
    {
console.log('loop i value-- >', i )  // ------------------
    if (i == randNum)
      {
console.log('(i == randNum) is true')  // ------------------
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You are lucky (" + randNum + ")";
      btnLuck[i].style.backgroundColor = "green"
      }
    else 
      {
console.log('(i == randNum) is false') // ------------------
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Other btn is lucky (" + randNum + ")";
      btnLuck[i].style.backgroundColor = "red"
  } } }
```

```html
<button onclick="randomNumber()">Lucky number 0</button>
<button onclick="randomNumber()">Lucky number 1</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: I added some `console.log()` in your code for showing executions steps -- you could use this old technique for debugging yourself your code

Comment: Trace through the script's execution in your head, or by using your browser's debugger, and you'll see what's happening.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For loop only outputs last iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35139126/for-loop-only-outputs-last-iteration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for something like that ?

```js
const
  demo_El  = document.querySelector('#demo')
, buttons  = document.querySelectorAll('button.forRandom') // first is°0 !
, replayBt = document.querySelector('#replay-button')

buttons.forEach( (btn,indexButton) =>
  {
  btn.textContent = `Lucky number ${indexButton +1}` // zero is blown by the wind 
  
  btn.onclick =_=> randomNumberTesting( btn,indexButton )
  })
replayBt.onclick =_=>
  {
  buttons.forEach(bt=>
    {
    bt.classList.remove('win', 'lost')
    bt.disabled = false
    })
  demo_El.textContent = '...?...'
  replayBt.disabled   = true
  }

function randomNumberTesting ( buttonElement, indexButton )
  {
  let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() *buttons.length) // [0...,n-1]

  buttons.forEach(bt=> bt.disabled = true )

  if (randNum===indexButton)
    {
    demo_El.textContent = `You are lucky (${randNum +1})`
    buttonElement.classList.add('win')
    }
  else
    {
    demo_El.textContent = `"Other btn is lucky (${randNum +1})`
    buttonElement.classList.add('lost')
    buttons[randNum].classList.add('win')
    }
  replayBt.disabled = false
  }
```

```css
.win  { background: lightgreen; }
.lost { background: lightcoral; }
```

```html
<button class="forRandom"></button>
<button class="forRandom"></button>
<button class="forRandom"></button>
<button class="forRandom"></button> <!-- or more... -->


<p id="demo">...?...</p>

<button id="replay-button" disabled>replay</button>
```

Comment: Thanks it was really helpful and solved my problem and gives a new insight . But can you tell about why my code is not running right

Comment: @Rana because you proceed on each button the `if` or `else` with your loop and rewrite 2 times your `demo_El` text

Answer (score 1):

I observed the problem you describe and if you are open to another solution then I hope the following might be of interest.

```js
/*
    Find the DOM elements of interest ~ one is a nodelist
*/
const demo=document.getElementById('demo');
const col=document.querySelectorAll('button');

/*
    assign an event handler to each button found and keep track of the
    buttons DOM nodelist index `i` as we will use that as a comparison
    to the random number generated.
*/
col.forEach((bttn,i)=>bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    // create the random number
  let randNum = Math.floor( Math.random() * 2 );
  
    // output
    let who;
      
    // find the nodelist index of the `other` button
  let index=( ( 1 - i ) + 1 );
      
    // find the `other` node
  let other=this.parentNode.querySelector('button:nth-of-type('+index+')');
  
    // reset styles for both buttons
  col.forEach(bttn=>bttn.classList.remove('red','green'));
  
  /*
    so if the random number equals the clicked button's nodelist index
    then assign the class and change the class of the `other` element
  */
  if( i===randNum ){
    this.classList.add('green');
    other.classList.add('red');
    who='You are lucky ('+randNum+')';
  }else{
    this.classList.add('red');
    other.classList.add('green');
    who='Other btn is lucky ('+randNum+')';
  }

  demo.innerText=who;
}));
```

```css
.red{background:red}
.green{background:green}
button:before{content:'Lucky Number - '}
```

```html
<button>0</button>
<button>1</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks it was really helpful and solved my problem and gives a new insight . But can you tell about why my code is not running right